# How to enable comments meta box for other author posts?

Tags: posts, comments, wp-admin

I am working with a ticket system which is a custom post type. Tickets can be created on the front end of the site. Registered users can post a new ticket, which can be moderated by administrator and needs to add a comment after approving it.  WordPress is not allowing other authors' posts to have new comments added by default. I mean, it only allow us to post a new comment, if we are the author of the post.

Is there any action, hook, or function that would allow administrators to add a new comment to any author's posts from the back end, while moderating the post.

Comment: You can see more in [WordPress Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) you can add another especific user for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers guys.  Finally I found solution for me issue. 
Once the post is published we can add comments.  If the post is pending it won't allow administrators to add a new comment.

The answer is simple,  if we publish the post we can add comments.